# how to chain async methods

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, method-chaining

The API I've written has several async methods that do not return a value, but still should be executed in the order they are called. I'd like to abstract the awaiting resolution from the end user so that they can chain method calls and expect that each promise is executed after the previous is resolved like so:

```
api = new Api();
api.doAsync().doAnotherAsync().doAThirdAsync();
```

It is not important that we get a value from these methods, just that they are executed in order. I have tried using a linked structure, but it hasn't been reliable.

```
class Api {
    resolvingMethodChain = false;
    constructor() {
        this._methodChain = {
            next: null,
            promise: Promise.resolve(),
        }
    }

    _chain(p) {
        this._methodChain.next = {
            promise: p,
            next: null,
        };

        // if we are not finished resolving the method chain, just append to the current chain
        if (!this.resolvingMethodChain) this._resolveMethodChain(this._methodChain);

        this._methodChain = this._methodChain.next;
        return this
    }

    async _resolveMethodChain(chain) {
        if (!this.resolvingPromiseChain) {
            this.resolvingPromiseChain = true;
        }

        // base case
        if (chain === null) {
            this.resolvingPromiseChain = false;
            return;
        }

        // resolve the promise in the current chain
        await chain.promise;

        // resolve the next promise in the chain
        this._resolvePromiseChain(c.next);   
    }
}
```

The `doAsync` methods would all defer to `_chain` like so

```
doAsync() {
    const p = new Promise(// do some async stuff);
    return _chain(p); // returns this and adds the promise to the methodChain
}
```

I know I could write it like this

```
async doAsync() {
    // do async thing
    return this;
}
```

And use it like this

```
doAsync.then(api => api).then(...)
```

But explicitly returning the `this` object from each `then` call is what I want to avoid if I can, it just doesn't seem as clean as the synchronous way of `api.doAsync().doAnotherAsync()...`

Comment: what about the normal use of promises do_Something().then(...).then(...) etc that is a simple promise chain, each is executed when the previous one is resolved, and each promise is resolved when the action in it (Async by nature) is done one way or another.

Comment: This would end up looking like this `doSomething().then(api => api).then(...)` I just wanted to avoid explicit returning what the promise returns in a callback each time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start with a simple wrapper around a Promise

```js
const effect = f => x =>
  (f (x), x)
  
const Api = (p = Promise.resolve ()) =>
  ({ foo: () => 
       Api (p.then (effect (x => console.log ('foo', x))))
     
   , bar: (arg) =>
       Api (p.then (effect (x => console.log ('bar', arg))))
     
  })
  
Api().foo().foo().bar(5)
// foo undefined
// foo undefined
// bar 5
```

We can add other functions that do more useful things. Note because we're using Promises, we can sequence synchronous or asynchronous functions with ease

```js
const effect = f => x =>
  (f (x), x)
  
const square = x =>
  x * x
  
const Api = (p = Promise.resolve ()) =>
  ({ log: () =>
       Api (p.then (effect (console.log)))
       
   , foo: () => 
       Api (p.then (effect (x => console.log ('foo', x))))
     
   , bar: (arg) =>
       Api (p.then (effect (x => console.log ('bar', arg))))
  
   , then: f =>
       Api (p.then (f))
  })

  
Api().log().then(() => 5).log().then(square).log()
// undefined
// 5
// 25
```

Add whatever functions you want now. This example shows functions that actually do something more realistic

```js
const effect = f => x =>
  (f (x), x)
  
const DB =
  { 10: { id: 10, name: 'Alice' }
  , 20: { id: 20, name: 'Bob' }
  }
  
const Database =
  { getUser: id =>
      new Promise (r =>
        setTimeout (r, 250, DB[id]))
  }
  
const Api = (p = Promise.resolve ()) =>
  ({ log: () =>
       Api (p.then (effect (console.log)))
       
   , getUser: (id) =>
       Api (p.then (() => Database.getUser (id)))
       
   , displayName: () =>
       Api (p.then (effect (user => console.log (user.name))))
  
  })

  
Api().getUser(10).log().displayName().log()
// { id: 10, name: 'Alice' }
// Alice
// { id: 10, name: 'Alice' }

Api().getUser(10).log().getUser(20).log().displayName()
// { id: 10, name: 'Alice' }
// { id: 20, name: 'Bob' }
// Bob
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need some sort of API object to chain `async` functions. If they don't accept input values as you've indicated by your example code, the pure promise-chain approach is almost identical without any boilerplate:

```js
async function delay (ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms)
  })
}

async function log (message) {
  console.log(message)
}

async function delay1s () {
  return delay(1000)
}

async function logNow () {
  const seconds = Math.round(performance.now() / 1000)

  return log(`${seconds}s`)
}

log('start')
  .then(delay1s)
  .then(logNow)
  .then(delay1s)
  .then(logNow)
  .then(delay1s)
  .then(() => log('stop'))
```

And as you can see, even functions that accept inputs simply need to be wrapped in an anonymous arrow function, which is quite trivial to do, and is far from unreadable.

Comment: The accepted answer did exactly what I was trying to accomplish, but I am giving a plus one because I actually find the implementation described here more obvious for the designer, and trivial for the end user.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a lib to solve this problem https://github.com/fsvieira/asyncake

I tried to make it really simple, in your case you just do:

```
const asyncChain = require('asyncake');
api = new Api();
const value = await asyncChain(api).doAsync().doAnotherAsync().doAThirdAsync();
```

you can even add it to your api like this

```
class Api {
   get chain () {
       return asyncChain(this);
   } 
   ...
}
```

Now just use it like this:

```
api = new Api();
const value = await api.chain.doAsync().doAnotherAsync().doAThirdAsync();
```

I hope it helps